# Native Ads In React Native

Tags: react-native, admob, native-ads

How do you implement AdMob's Native Ads in React Native? The best I've found is [react-native-admob](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob), but it only does fixed banners and full screen interstitials. How could I implement native ads *inside* my React Native app with AdMob or any other native ad provider?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's also react native facebook ads
Have a look: [React Native Facebook Ads](https://github.com/callstack-io/react-native-fbads)

This plugin allows you to implement native ads, only downside is that the installation process is a bit of a handful but it does work. It also requires [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) to be installed too so that your ads produce relevant ads to your users once they've logged in.

At this moment react-native-admob doesn't support native ads just yet, but you can implement it in a way that it's not fixed like so:

```
<ScrollView>
 <View>
  <Text>Add some content here</Text>
  <AdMobBanner
   bannerSize="smartBannerPortrait"
   adUnitID="you-ad-unit-id"
   testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
   didFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError} />
 </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It's too difficult to get FB ads in your app, even some test banners. Then I went with Admob though it doesn't support native ads at this moment.

Comment: Displaying banner ads in a scrollview is against google's admob policies and can get your ads/app suspended. They recommend to have fixed place in your layout to display banner ads and that they should not move with scroll.

Comment: is there is way to integrate https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-admob-dfp/v/2.0.0-beta.3.9.? or any dfp google ads.

Answer (score 0):

Appodeal provides native ads. It asks you when creating your app which framework you want to use.

**EDIT:** Appodeal now discontinues the support of their react-native wrapper